# isFinite(Number.MAX_VALUE + 1) returns true?

Tags: javascript, numbers, max

I'm learning JavaScript, and there is an example in the book:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number Example 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var result = Number.MAX_VALUE + 1;
        alert(isFinite(result));    // the book says it should be false, but I got "true"

    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the alert message **"true"** running this code, anything wrong with it?

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE+1 == Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: The book is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number.MAX_VALUE` plus any other value returns `Number.MAX_VALUE`

So, for example, the following statement is `true`:

```
 Number.MAX_VALUE + 1 ===  Number.MAX_VALUE + 2
```

Since, we're at it, the following statement is also `true`:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + 1 ===  Number.MAX_VALUE + 999999
```

At some point, the statement becomes `false` though:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + 1 ===  Number.MAX_VALUE + 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 // true
```

But adding one more `9` returns `false`:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + 1 ===  Number.MAX_VALUE + 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 // false
```

Yet, if we add `Number.MAX_VALUE` to itself, it returns the following:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + (Number.MAX_VALUE) === Infinity
```

Where it gets a bit tricky is with multiplication. When we multiply `Number.MAX_VALUE` with anything higher than `1` it returns `Infinity`

```
Number.MAX_VALUE * 1.00000001 === Infinity
```

Comment: No. Try with larger values.

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE + 1 === Number.MAX_VALUE + X` becomes false somewhere between `X = 1e+291` and `X = 1e+292` (whereas `Number.MAX_VALUE` is `1.7976931348623157e+308`).